# How to abort applying group policy when it is stuck for too long?

Tags: windows-server-2008, group-policy

I had a problem with a Win2k8 Domain Controller and had to restart it.

It restarted with no issues and reached the "PRESS CTRL + DEL TO LOGON" screen. And so I did a usual logon with an administrative domain account and it started to apply group policy.

It processed mapped drive and some other stuff before it reach printer policy and then it got stuck for more than an hour.

What is the proper way to troubleshoot or abort applying group policy?

Comment: Why would a.printer policy be applying for a local dc logon?

Comment: Try pulling out the network cable.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft has a loooong page on [Troubleshooting Group Policy Using Event Logs](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749336%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).

To supplement that I would follow [Mark Russinovich's advice](http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2010/01/13/3305263.aspx) on troubleshooting logins in general with Process Monitor and psexec.

For problems occurring during boot up (as opposed to login) it's also worth looking into Xbootmgr.